# Nginx isn't storing cache

Tags: nginx, flask, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I'm trying to allow [nginx caching](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/content-cache/content-caching/) in the simplest form. But for some reason it's not working. I'm currently using nginx with gunicorn and flask on an ec2 instance.

This is my `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file:

```
user nginx;

...

proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=mycache:10m;
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;

server {
    listen 80;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/agori.access.log  main;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/agori.error.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_cache mycache;
        proxy_cache_valid any 48h;
        proxy_buffering on;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/ec2-user/src/project.sock;
    }
}
```

when check the `/var/cache/nginx` folder, it's empty. These are the folders permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 nginx root    6 May 13 14:03 nginx
```

This is the request and respond headers:

[image]

PS: This is on mobile(ios)

Comment: Hi. Why are you using `/home/ec2-user/cache` as cache folder? Can nginx user write in this folder? Try to use the default folder for this, like `/var/cache/nginx`

Comment: This seems to be user permission issues. You should not use your own home folder as the `nginx` will not be running under the `ec2-user` user

Comment: Hello, I've updated the question and change the cache folder, I'm still getting the same result.

Comment: Did you try to leave out the `proxy_cache_valid` line? Also, it looks like the example on the nginx page does not say `proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx keys_zone=mycache:10m;` but `one` instead of `mycache`. I am not sure what the `one` should be refering to, but maybe you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me that something in your Nginx config might not be correct (syntax error or not supported by your Nginx version). In most of the case I encountered so far that was the case for me.

You probably know [Nginx' reverse proxy example](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/reverseproxycachingexample/) which features the following configuration

> ```
> http {
>    proxy_cache_path  /data/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m   inactive=24h  max_size=1g;
>    server {
>       location / {
>         proxy_pass             http://1.2.3.4;
>         proxy_set_header       Host $host;
>         proxy_buffering        on;
>         proxy_cache            STATIC;
>         proxy_cache_valid      200  1d;
>         proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating
>                                http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
>       }
>    }
> }
> ```

I tried to compare that with your configuration file and I my debugging approach would be:

1. Does nginx log your requests in `access_log`?
2. Try to remove whether the example configuration file works after minimal modifications.
3. Replace the `any` with a `200` for a start and see whether that works.
4. If that works, put in step by step all additional config lines like the `proxy_cache_methods` line.